# No operator "==" matches these operands for sf::RectangleShape

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm getting the following error when trying to compare two `sf::RectangleShape` objects:

> No operator "==" matches these operands.

You can see in the following code that both types (`snake` and `addsnakey[0]`) are `sf::RectangleShape`. Why do I get a compiler error when I try to compare two `sf::RectangleShape`?

Below is the offending code. I added a comment where the error is:

```
sf::RectangleShape snake;

//increases size of the snake
sf::RectangleShape addsnake()
{
    sf::RectangleShape addsnake1;
    addsnake1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 25));
    addsnake1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    addsnake1.setPosition(100, 100);
    sf::RectangleShape addsnake2;
    addsnake2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 30));
    addsnake2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    addsnake2.setPosition(100, 100);
    sf::RectangleShape addsnake3;
    addsnake3.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    addsnake3.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 35));
    addsnake3.setPosition(100, 100);
    sf::RectangleShape addsnake4;
    addsnake4.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 40));
    addsnake4.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    addsnake4.setPosition(100, 100);
    sf::RectangleShape addsnakey[4] = { addsnake1, addsnake2, addsnake3, addsnake4 };
    if (snake == snake) //problem here (No operator "==" matches these operands)
        return addsnakey[0];
    else if (snake == addsnakey[0])
        return addsnakey[1];
    else if (snake == addsnakey[1])
        return addsnakey[2];
    else if (snake == addsnakey[2])
        return addsnakey[3];
    else if (snake == addsnakey[3])
        return addsnakey[4];
}
```

Comment: The code is nonsense anyway: `if (a == a)` How can `snake` not equal `snake`?

Comment: Do you expect people to guess which single line, amongst the pages of code you posted, is the one that results in this compilation error?

Comment: I had added a comment beside it. It's not far inside. It's in the first function in the code.

Comment: I [formatted your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36120974/2) to remove the irrelevant parts of code and formatted the code to make more sense; however, there are problems with the code which might still indicate downvotes, namely the line `if (snake == snake)` which will never not be true (but perhaps was test code when `snake == addsnakey[0]` wasn't working?) and trying to access `addsnakey[4]` which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equality operator defined for the `sf::RectangleShape` class.  You will need to create one, and decide on exactly what properties determine equality.

Perhaps size and position are what you care about.  So you could define the following function:

```
bool operator==( const sf::RectangleShape & a, const sf::RectangleShape & b )
{
    return a.getSize() == b.getSize() && a.getPosition() == b.getPosition();
}
```

This would be okay, because both the `getSize` and `getPosition` member functions return a `Vector2f` which *does* have an equality operator.  You might care about about `getScale` too.

Naturally, it's up to you to determine what constitutes equality.  The lack of an equality operator on the `sf::RectangleShape` is not surprising, given that it does a lot, including texturing etc.  It's obviously not the kind of thing you expect to be comparing with other objects.

See [Reference for sf::Vector2f](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Vector2.php)

Comment: BIG WARNING: `sf::Vector2f`'s equality operator does **not** take into account floating point imprecisions! You should not use such code.